# Convert transparent black to white with only GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, mbtiles, gdal-calc

I have an RGBA [foo.tif](https://github.com/eddy-geek/mypastebin/blob/master/20210210/foo.tif) with `NoData Value=0` on all 4 bands.

Unfortunately **values that are transparent black** (0 0 0 0), when converting to jpg, become black instead of no data becoming white like I would expect.

I am trying to work around it with a basic `color = if R+G+B==0 then white else color` for each band:

```bsh
gdal_calc.py -R foo.tif --R_band=1 -G foo.tif --G_band=2 -B foo.tif --B_band=3 --outfile=result.tif \
  --calc="where(R+G+B,R,255)" --calc="G*where(R+G+B,G,255)" --calc="where(R+G+B,B,255)" --overwrite
```

Or this "arithmetic-only" variant

```bsh
gdal_calc.py -R foo.tif --R_band=1 -G foo.tif --G_band=2 -B foo.tif --B_band=3 --outfile=result.tif \
  --calc='R*((R+G+B)!=0) + 255*((R+G+B)==0)' --calc='G*((R+G+B)!=0) + 255*((R+G+B)==0)' --calc='B*((R+G+B)!=0) + 255*((R+G+B)==0)' --overwrite
```

But the result is not as I expect:
Input / Output

[image: input]
[image: output]

Al lot of colors (orange...) have turned white, which is the output's nodata value. And if I add `--NoDataValue=0` I get this:

[image: nodata]

Which makes me think the `Blue` `Band 3` is somehow the only one impacted by the input "nodata" value of 0. How can I fix this? I have GDAL 3.2 *without* the new `-hideNoData` flag :-(

Or better, can I make a jpg with a white "bottom" with pure GDAL (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705094/using-gdal-translate-from-tif-to-jpg-how-to-set-background-to-white), but without rasterio because I actually want mbtiles jpg in the end)

```
gdalinfo foo.tif
...
Band 1 Block=390x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=390x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=390x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
Band 4 Block=390x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  NoData Value=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need JPG output, read after the first example.
But, in this specific case, you might be better off with PNG output if that works for you.

```
gdal_translate -q -of PNG -co WORLDFILE=YES foo.tif foo3.png
```

Output:

[image: tif to png]

Converting to JPG is not straightforward as for PNG but try setting the nodata for all bands to 255 first if you want a white background n JPG, i.e., "255, 255, 255, 255" employing an intermediate VRT file. Then convert the VRT to JPG.

```
gdalbuildvrt -hidenodata -vrtnodata "255 255 255 255" foo.vrt foo.tif
gdal_translate -q -of JPEG foo.vrt foo3.jpg
```

Output:
[image: tif to vrt to jpg]

You may have to refine the above logic as some of the colors appear to have changed.

I guess these are the points where one of the RGBA values were "0" and set as nodata in your original TIF file (check using a TIF viewer or QGIS).

But this is the logic you want if you need JPG as output.

Comment: Yes, nodata is per-band so it's not actually an adequate mean of conveying the whole information. And indeed png is better, but bigger. I did manage to reduce png size with pngnq as postprocess, so I'll stick with that. Thx